# Advice troubleshooting error "Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated"

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have created this function in bigquery, but whenever I try to call it I get a correlated query error.  I cannot really see a way around this or how to do this in joins, and the function works perfectly when using test values rather than queried tables.  Any advice on how to get this to work properly appreciated.  Function here.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION `database.function` (x DATE, y INT64) AS (
(WITH dates AS (

SELECT 
    dates,
    CASE 
        WHEN dates BETWEEN '2021-04-02' AND '2021-07-01' THEN 'q1_fy22'
        WHEN dates BETWEEN '2021-07-02' AND '2021-09-30' THEN 'q2_fy22'
        WHEN dates BETWEEN '2021-10-01' AND '2021-12-30' THEN 'q3_fy22'
        WHEN dates BETWEEN '2021-12-31' AND '2022-03-31' THEN 'q4_fy22'
        WHEN dates BETWEEN '2022-04-01' AND '2022-06-30' THEN 'q1_fy23'
        WHEN dates BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-09-29' THEN 'q2_fy23'
        WHEN dates BETWEEN '2022-09-30' AND '2022-12-29' THEN 'q3_fy23'
        WHEN dates BETWEEN '2022-12-30' AND '2023-03-30' THEN 'q4_fy23'
        WHEN dates BETWEEN '2023-03-31' AND '2023-06-29' THEN 'q1_fy24'
        WHEN dates BETWEEN '2023-06-30' AND '2023-09-28' THEN 'q2_fy24'
        WHEN dates BETWEEN '2023-09-29' AND '2023-12-28' THEN 'q3_fy24'
        WHEN dates BETWEEN '2023-12-29' AND '2024-03-28' THEN 'q4_fy24'
        ELSE 'future'
    END as quarter
FROM 
UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE('2021-04-02'), DATE('2024-03-28'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
    ) as dates
),


d1 as (
select dates.dates as day, orr.es_id, orr.or_metric
from dates
left join es_team.metric_overrides orr on dates.quarter = orr.or_quarter
),

final as(
select es_id, day, or_metric from d1 
where or_metric = 'Resolves'
)

select 
case 
    when x IN (select day from final) and y IN (select es_id from final)
    THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END)
```

Would be very grateful for any tips on avoiding this. It is the querying the metric_overrides table that is causing the issues.

Here is the code calling the function.

```
SELECT
    es_daily.full_name  AS es_daily_full_name,
    AVG(CASE WHEN (csat_inflow_log.channel = 'chat') and functions.this_function(es_daily.date, es_daily.es_id) is false THEN csat_response_log.csat_score  ELSE NULL END) AS chat_csat
FROM TEAM_TABLE  AS es_daily
LEFT JOIN CSAT_TABLE AS csat_response_log ON es_daily.date =  (DATE(csat_response_log.timestamp , 'Europe/London'))
      AND es_daily.es_id = csat_response_log.es_id
LEFT JOIN INFLOW_TABLE  AS csat_inflow_log ON csat_response_log.ticket_id = csat_inflow_log.ticket_id
GROUP BY
    1
```

Comment: Can you add your code that shows how you are calling the function when you get this error?  Perhaps showing the actual call that fails and the call that works with test values?

Comment: Can you add the test values and maybe a queried value to check how it is sending it? Additionally, you can delete the `final` temporary table and add the `where` clause in the `d1` temporary table.

Comment: added the code calling the function, and deleted the other.  I have actually since found a workaround to this, I have just generated an expanded table based on date arrays and int values and then I just run the queries in case when statements rather than the function and it takes them just fine (which is odd as afaik its basically doing the exact same thing as the function).